# Problems sending and receiving data between php and perl?

Tags: php, perl

I have a problem in sending and receiving data between php and perl socket:

-Problem:

- php can not send all byte data to perl socket
- Perl socket can not receiving all data from php .

Here code php:

```
function save(){ 
    unset($_SESSION['info']); 
    unset($_SESSION['data']); 
    global $config,$ip; 
    $start=$_POST['config']; 
    $fp = fsockopen($_SESSION['ip'], $config['port'], $errno, $errstr, 30); 
    if(!$fp) { 
        $_SESSION['info']="Not connect "; 
        transfer("Not   connect".$ip, "index.php?com=server&act=info"); 
    } else { 
        $_SESSION['info']="Save config - ".$ip; 
        fwrite($fp,$start); 
        transfer("Sending data to ".$ip, "index.php?com=server&act=info");    
    } 
}
```

Here code perl socket:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use Carp; 
use POSIX qw( setsid ); 

use IO::Socket; 

$| = 1; 

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET ( 
                              LocalHost => '192.168.150.3', 
                              LocalPort => '5000', 
                              Proto => 'tcp', 
                              Listen => 5, 
                              Reuse => 1 
                           ); 
die "Coudn't open socket" unless $socket; 
print "\nTCPServer Waiting for client on port 5000"; 
my $client_socket = ""; 
while ($client_socket = $socket->accept()) { 
    my $recieved_data =" "; 
    my $send_data=" "; 
    my $peer_address = $client_socket->peerhost(); 
    my $peer_port = $client_socket->peerport(); 
    print "\n I got a connection from ( $peer_address , $peer_port ) "; 
    print "\n SEND( TYPE q or Q to Quit):"; 
    $client_socket->recv($recieved_data,20000); 
    #while (defined($recieved_data = <$client_socket>)) { 
        if ( $recieved_data eq 'q' or $recieved_data eq 'Q' ) { 
            close $client_socket; 
            last; 
        } 
        elsif ($recieved_data eq 'start' or $recieved_data eq 'START' ) { 
            $send_data = `/etc/init.d/squid start`; 
        } 
        elsif ($recieved_data eq 'restart' or $recieved_data eq 'RESTART' ) { 
            $send_data =  `/etc/init.d/squid restart`; 
        } 
        elsif ($recieved_data eq 'stop' or $recieved_data eq 'STOP' ) { 
            $send_data =  `/etc/init.d/squid stop`; 
        } 
        elsif ($recieved_data eq 'hostname' or $recieved_data eq 'HOSTNAME' ) {
            $send_data= `hostname`; 
        } 
        elsif ($recieved_data eq 'view-config' or $recieved_data eq 'VIEW-CONFIG' ) { 
            $send_data = `cat /etc/squid/squid.conf` ; 
        } 
        else { 
            #print  $recieved_data; 
            open OUTPUT_FILE, '> /root/data' or die("can not open file"); 
            print OUTPUT_FILE $recieved_data; 
            close OUTPUT_FILE 
        } 
    #} 
    if ($send_data eq 'q' or $send_data eq 'Q') { 
        $client_socket->send ($send_data); 
        close $client_socket; 
        last; 
    } 
    else { 
        $client_socket->send($send_data); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you know its not working? What are you seeing it do instead? What have you done to track down the issue so far?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to actually write the code that parses the received data. TCP is a byte-stream protocol that does not preserve application message boundaries. Unless that happens to be exactly what you need (and it clearly isn't here), you need to develop and implement a protocol on top of TCP that provides the capabilities your application needs. For one thing, you need some way to find the end of a command. Your code provides absolutely no way for the receiver to do that.

You really should invest the time in writing a protocol specification, no matter how simple the protocol is. The protocol specification should clearly specify the message formats at the byte level. The protocol specification should clearly specify how the client identifies when it has a complete message.

Then you actually have to write code to implement that protocol.

In this case, you could simply write a zero byte to mark the end of a message. Then code the receiver to keep receiving data until it receives a zero byte. Then it knows everything before that is a message.